# What is the most secure way to invite an unregistered user to my app?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm working on a React app with an Express backend, with Passport for authentication via JWTs. A registered user needs to be able to send an invitation to someone else who is unregistered, to come use the application. The unregistered user should not be required to register in order to see a subset of our content. **THIS IS IMPORTANT** - the unregistered user needs to be able to have access to some data that belongs to the registered user and would otherwise be unviewable without being authenticated. I built an invitation model to track these invites, who sent them, who they're being sent to, etc.

What is the best/most secure way to identify this user?

My current guess is to create a unique string and store that in the invitation object and pass that to the unregistered user via email. So they will have a link to our app with `?invite_id=SOME_ID_HERE` appended at the end. When they reach our app we will verify that the string matches an invite in our DB.

Is this the best approach? Should I be doing something more secure, maybe a pair of public and private keys? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's best to keep this as a random ID in your database.  That way, the users can be removed later.  And, if you do associate this new user with that random ID later, you can use an existing profile that you're already storing rather than having them start from scratch.

In other words, create a new ID for this user but set it up so that they can only access things via this URL until they create an account.